# Updating the product array in opencart

Tags: opencart

I am trying to update both the quantity and total of a product in the current cart in a new file i have created in the root opencart folder.

First I grab the total and quantity which have been posted here from another file. Then I load the products array. Then if $total and $quantity exist and are not equal to 0, I update the products array with the new values for quantity and total. My problem is I am not quite sure how to load the products array and update it with the new values for quantity and total.

This is what I have come up with so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$total = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['total']));
$quantity = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['quantity']));

$this->data['products'] = array();
$products = $this->cart->getProducts();

if ($total && $total != 0 && $quantity && $quantity != 0){
product['quantity'] = $quantity;
product['total'] = $total;
}
?>
```

Comment: This condition: `if ($total && $total != 0 && $quantity && $quantity != 0){` should be shortened to `if ($total && $quantity) {`, because condition `if ($var) {}` also checks for `if ($var != 0) {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean how can you update the current live cart items, they're stored in a key value pair in the session under the `cart` key, so you can manipulate/read them from

```
$this->session->data['cart']
```

To see the inner workings of how the cart reads them, you can take a look at the `getProducts()`method in `/system/library/cart.php`